# JDK 1.6 and Xerces?

Tags: java, xml, legacy

In my current project, we target a JDK 1.6 Runtime environment. For legacy rasons, Xerces JAR files are bundled in the application.

These are no longer needed right? The JDK has (for a while) had XML parsing libraries bundled in the JDK?

Comment: Why not just try it without bundling them?

Comment: They are no more or less needed than with 1.5. 1.6 has some bizarre forked version of Xerces, just a different bizarre version than 1.5. As per @DaveNewton, the only way to tell if it will work for you is to try it.

Comment: I think I have to run some dependency analysis software on our project. I would not be sureprised if some open source framework that we use depend on Xerces directly instead of using JAXP.

Comment: JDK Xerces has some serious unresolved issues and it is not clear which version of Apache Xerces is in each JDK. I got a [complete parsing failure on valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843482) even in the recent JDK 1.8_152 which I could simply make disappear by including Xerces 2.11 on the class path. (Although that is only from 2011.) Luckily, JAXP interfaces and ServieLoader make it really easy to switch implementations!

Comment: @RobertJackWill  Xerces-J 2.12.0 released (30 April 2018), see here: http://xerces.apache.org/news.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bundling an XML parser has not been necessary since 1.4 when [JAXP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html) was added to the JRE. You should use JAXP and not directly call Xerces. Internally, the JRE bundles and uses Xerces anyways (with a "com.sun" prefix).

Comment: This is correct. After some Googling, It seems that JDK 1.4 had JAXP 1.1 support and bundled the Apache classed with unchaged class names; causing heaps of problems when people wanted to use newer versions than the one bundled with the JDK. (http://people.apache.org/~edwingo/jaxp-faq.html#JDK14)

Answer (score 22):

These XML services plug in application environment using so-called "service provider" mechanism.

It works as follows:

1. It tries to find system property that exactly points to factory class, that should be used. E.g. `-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=<some class>`.
2. If system property was not found `FactoryFinder` looks for property in special properties file. For example `${java.home}/lib/jaxp.properties`.
3. If file property was not found FactoryFinder looks for service description in class path `META-INF/services/<some service>`, e.g. `META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory`.
   It is a file that should contain factory class name for example `org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl`.
4. If there are no such files in class path java uses its default factory implementation.

So if you do not have system property pointing to evident factory class java will choose suitable implementation quietly.

Comment: This is the way the standard static `SAXParserFactory` code works, see [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#newInstance%28%29) for these and some more details. These are the ways to couple initial JDK/JRE bundled mechanisms with an XML library of your choice. There is also a possibility to substitute the JDK/JRE bundled XML libraries completely using _Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism:_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards/ , e.g. `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=path_to_folder_containing_new_library_jars`.

Answer (score 12):

The parser in the JDK was a fork of Xerces, but it is very buggy. I would recommend production applications always to use the Apache version of the parser in preference. The bugs are rare, but they are unpredictable, and they don't only affect corner cases that aren't seen in real life; I've seen many cases where quite boring XML documents are being parsed, and corrupt data is passed to the application for attribute values. Sun/Oracle have shown no interest in fixing the problem. Use Apache Xerces every time.

**UPDATE (2018)**

The problems with the JDK version of Xerces seem to have been resolved in Java 8, as far as I can see, so this advice is out of date.

Comment: Hi. Do you have som references/descriptions for bugs in the JDK parser(s)? And what JDK versions are you talking about?

Comment: When people send me Saxon bug reports that turn out to be due to JDK parser problems, I no longer bother to report the problems to Oracle because doing so appears to have no effect. So no, I can't cite references.

Comment: Since Java 9 a pretty stable Version of Xerces (v2.11) is included in JDK. So no need to use the Apache Version of Xerces from Java 9. [see](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044086)

Answer (score 2):

Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism works just fine. Djava.endorsed.dirs=path_to_folder_containing_new_library_jars  will resolve the issue with JDK 1.6.

I have verified the above solution in the context of Thymleaf. In some cases if you go for LEGACYHTML5 mode, and if you use NekoHtml parser for Autocorrecting the unclosed html tags,
Neko has dependency on Xerces jars. Setting the classpath does not solve the problem.

Thanks  s-n-ushakov.