# Override Xerces implementation to create a XMLEventReader through XMLInputFactory

Tags: java, xml, xerces, stax

The Xerces version that ships with Java has a [bug when dealing with empty XML elements for XML version 1.1 input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727288/why-does-the-stax-parser-think-this-is-valid-xml-1-0-but-not-1-1). This bug has long been fixed in Apache's Xerces release (since 2.6.2).

I want to create a XMLEventReader through the XMLInputFactory interface. Something like this:

```
XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
```

Simply placing the Xerces jars into the classpath does not seem to work here. In fact I do not see that Apaches Xerces release extends XMLInputFactory, which seems to be a prerequisite for creating an implementation-specific input factory.

Is there a way to force XMLInputFactory.newFactory to use Apaches Xerces release from the classpath?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794556/2071828) might be of help. You need to set a system property to tell the factory which class to instantiate.

Comment: Unfortunately Xerces does not seem to have an implementation of XMLInputFactory. At least I could not find one.

Comment: Any news on this? I have very similar issue in Java 10.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

this version includes StAX and it will override default StAX impl automatically, useing jar Service Provider mechanizm

Comment: Unfortunately our project does not use Maven. All libraries are set using by setting the classpath.

Comment: That's OK just download xerces 2.11.0 jar from here http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi

Comment: It does not seem to work. I tried the sample code from the question [linked in my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727288/why-does-the-stax-parser-think-this-is-valid-xml-1-0-but-not-1-1) with only your Maven dependency on Xerces 2.11 in it.