# Convert org.w3c.dom.Document to File file

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file as object in Java as org.w3c.dom.Document doc and I want to convert this into File file. How can I convert the type Document to File?
thanks

I want to add metadata elements in an existing xml file (standard dita) with type File. 
I know a way to add elements to the file, but then I have to convert the file to a org.w3c.dom.Document. I did that with the method loadXML:

```
private Document loadXML(File f) throws Exception{ 
DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
return builder.parse(f);
```

After that I change the org.w3c.dom.Document, then I want to continue with the flow of the program and I have to convert the Document doc back to a File file.

What is a efficient way to do that? Or what is a better solution to get some elements in a xml File without converting it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a Transformer class to output the entire XML content to a File, as showed below:

```
Document doc =...

// write the content into xml file
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("/tmp/output.xml"));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With JDK 1.8.0 a short way is to use the built-in XMLSerializer (which was introduced with JDK 1.4 as a fork of Apache Xerces)

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer;

Document doc = //use your method loadXML(File f)

//change Document

java.io.Writer writer = new java.io.FileWriter("MyOutput.xml");
XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer(writer, null);
xml.serialize(doc);
```

Use an object of type `OutputFormat` to configure output, for example like this:

```
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(Method.XML, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString(), true);
format.setIndent(4);
format.setLineWidth(80);
format.setPreserveEmptyAttributes(true);
format.setPreserveSpace(true);
XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer(writer, format);
```

Note that the classes are from `com.sun.*` package which is not documented and therefore [generally is not seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794281/jdk-1-6-and-xerces) as the preferred way of doing things. However, with `javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys` you cannot specify the amount of indentation or line width for example. So, if this is important then this solution should help.

Comment: This is a shorter than using the transformer in the accepted answer, but shouldn't we stay away from `com.sun` classes?

Comment: Depends on your needs or policies. Please note that `com.sun.*` is not `sun.*` This code has proved to be stable for more than a year now and other well-known frameworks use `com.sun.*` as well. But, yes, in the unlikely event of an incompatible change, you have to be prepared to change your code. Which should not be a big deal, if your company policy contains some words like `agile` or `continuous refactoring`. For further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package